# React function component executes twice?

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, react-functional-component

I have a simple React function component and noticed some strange behavior while trying to use hooks. It persists even after commenting out all content of the function so I don't think it has anything to do with changing state or props.

this code:

```
let renderNum = 0;

export default function MyComponent(props: any) {
  console.dir(props)
  renderNum += 1;
  console.log('renderNum ' + renderNum)

  return (
    <>
      <h1>renderNum {renderNum}</h1>
    </>
  )
};
```

results in the following behavior:
[prtScr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uePCt.png)

1. the counter starts at 0
2. there's a console.dir(props)
3. the counter is incremented by 1
4. there's another console.dir(props) <--- 2nd reder!?
5. the view displays *renderNum 2*

How is this possible?

Why is the counter incremented twice?

And even so - why is there no second log of the counter?

How can the console.dir() be executed twice but not console.log()?

notes:

- the props never change (empty list)
- tried disabling all other code, including all other components in parent
- removed all uses of context or redux stuff
- tried alternative ordering of logging and incrementing
- I'm a newbie with React and might miss some basic fact
- this is relevant to me because I'm trying to add dynamic [RTK listeners](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rtk-incubator/action-listener-middleware) and need to add it inside this component; otherwise cannot use hooks

finally:

If this is expected behavior (), how else can I add a listener to a redux-toolkit action that does not alter any store value? I'd post this a separate question but not sure how to formulate it properly.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I saw it but overlooked it. Indeed, removing the strictMode tag prevents 2nd render. I find this very strange but have much to read for now. Post an answer if you'd like me to accept and close.

Comment: The duplicate link will be more helpful to future visitors than me posting another answer. It is strange, but if you dive deeper into how `useEffects` and `useState` work, and how stale closures/etc can be issues, it makes a lot of sense why double renders would help reduce bugs